# How to get list of a field value as the result in mongodb with Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb

I want to get a list of a field's value from documents.
How can I write the following in spring

`db.collection.find({"name" : "tom"}).map(function(u) return u.age)`

If I use

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name).in("tom))
Aggregation.group("age")
```

I get list Objects with `{_id, age}` but I want `List<String> ages`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, You don't need to map to get just the `age` field from the collection, you can just use projection.

Projection returns `_id` by default, so, you might want to specify it to be not returned if that's so.

i.e `db.collection.find({}, {'age': 1, '_id': 0})`

In Spring Data, you can perform a similar operation with `include()` and `exclude()`.

i.e

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("age").exclude("id");
List<User> usersWithJustAgeInformation = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```

but this will also return an object of type User from which you can very easily filter the `List <String> ages` with stream, map and collect.

Eg.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("age").exclude("id");
List<String> ages = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class).stream().map(User::getAge).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations for more information and examples of projection and aggregation.

Comment: I want to do it in repository lvl on database query. As I understand spring can't return List<String> than I need to use java to get it from document?

Comment: It can probably return List<String>, but you'd have to use $project in aggregation and suppress _id field, look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#examples and the link I included in the answer.

However, performance-wise I think a simple query like the one in the answer will be faster.